# ContentResolver query selection where value is in range or array

Tags: android, selection, android-contentresolver

I am working on a basic project involving `CalendarContract.Calendars` and `CalendarContract.Events`. I have selected a calendar list with a simple selection rule( with a wildcard), so I essentially have a list of calendar ids I want. My goal is to select events only with calendar IDs that are in the list of IDs from previous step.

**I am wondering if it's possible to use a selection similar to SQL** `WHERE [column name] IN [list]`, to select where values of a particular column are in given list of values (something in lines of `"CalendarID IN ?"` and passing list of IDs as an argument).

At the moment I am considering building selection string to check each ID (pseudo-code below), but it seems wasteful.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

string selection="((CalendarID = ?) "; //at this point in code I know there is at least 1 ID to be checked
for(int i=1;i<calendarIDList.size();i++){
   selection+="OR (CalendarID = ?)"
}
selection+=")"
//So basically build a string like "((CalendarID = ?) OR ((CalendarID = ?).....)"
Cursor cur =cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, CALENDAR_PROJECTION, selection, calendarIDList, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a long time ago, but perhaps someone is looking for an answer even today.

The selection String can be build basically exactly as you expected.

```
import android.provider.CalendarContract

//sample list with calendar IDs (to be replaced by your actual list)
val calendarIdList = listOf(1, 2, 4)

//build selection with calendar IDs
val selectionString = calendarIdList.joinToString(
        prefix = CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + "== ",
        separator = " OR " + CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + "== "
    )
```

Optionally, further combinations are possible:

```
val selection = "(" + selectionString + ")" +
            " AND " + CalendarContract.Events.DELETED + " != 1" +
            " AND " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + beginTime.timeInMillis +
            " AND " + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " < " + endTime.timeInMillis
```